# Parsing XML String Returned from WebRequest

Tags: c#, xml, parsing

I have an xml string returned from a HTTPWebRequest which I need to parse through to obtain the correct mailing address.  The  tag contains a child tag of  which will either be Primary or Alternate.  If the tag equals Alternate I will use the address values for that CustAddr, but if there is no Alternate then I will use the primary as the default.  In C# how would I do this using the System.Xml.Linq library?

```
<Customer>
 <CustInfo>
  <CustAddr>
   <FullName>MY PRIMARY NAME</FullName>
   <Addr1>PRIMARY ADDRESS1</Addr1>
   <Addr2>PRIMARY ADDRESS2</Addr2>
   <Addr3>PRIMARY ADDRESS3</Addr3>
   <Addr4></Addr4>
   <Addr5></Addr5>
   <AddrCode>PRIMARY</AddrCode>
  </CustAddr>
  <CustAddr>
   <FullName>MY ALTERNATE ADDRESS LINE 1</FullName>
   <Addr1>TEST ALT ADDRESS LINE1</Addr1>
   <Addr2>TEST ALT ADDRESS LINE2</Addr2>
   <Addr3>TEST ALT ADDRESS LINE3</Addr3>
   <Addr4></Addr4>
   <Addr5></Addr5>
   <AddrCode>ALTERNATE</AddrCode>
  </CustAddr>
 </CustInfo>
</Customer>
```

Comment: explain better the issue here

Answer (score 0):

Try following xml linq.  I used Regex to get addresses.  Needed to avoid getting AddrCode as part of the address.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml = File.ReadAllText(FILENAME);

            //use parse to take string returned from request
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

            KeyValuePair<string, List<string>> results = doc.Descendants("CustAddr").Where(x => (string)x.Element("AddrCode") == "PRIMARY")
                .Select(x => new KeyValuePair<string, List<string>>((string)x.Element("FullName"), x.Elements().Where(y => Regex.IsMatch(y.Name.LocalName, @"Addr\d")).Select(y => (string)y).ToList())).FirstOrDefault(); 

        }
    }
}
```